# Compilation Error when using kendo.mvc.ui in my web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have an application in which I am using `Kendo.Mvc.UI` now I am creating another project in which I want to use `Kendo.Mvc.UI` so I added `Kendo.Mvc.UI` my bin folder see below Image for reference[image]

and added the below code my main `web.config` in Pages > Namespaces

```
<add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />//the same code is working in my previous project.
```

and the below line in my `web.config` of which is in `views` folder

```
<add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" /> //this is same in both the web.config
```

but I am Getting the below error

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'kendo'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 56:`<add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />`
>
> Line 57:`<add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />`
>
> Line 58:`<add namespace="kendo.mvc.ui" />`
>
> Line 59:`</namespaces>`
>
> Line 60:`</pages>`

Comment: Did you have something which able to convert/transform into lowercase? AFAIK the namespace in web.config must be match as actual namespace in reference list, I never seen a namespace in web.config could be converted to lowercase beforehand.

Comment: have you actually added the Kendo.Mvc.dll into the references for the project as opposed to just importing it into the bin folder?

Comment: @DavidShorthose imported into bin folder and added reference in references

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto no I did not add anything, and it also confused me, how it can change it to lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a project I currently have the following should work: in the main `web.config`

The directive should be here:

```
  <system.web>

   ...All other options removed for brevity....
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

then in the web.config under your `Views` folder it should look like this:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Which based on your first image looks correct.

Assuming you have the `web.config` files configured correctly then intellisense should kick in after a shutdown and reopen of the project (if it doesn't recognise it straight away) when you type something like `@Html.Kendo().<control here>`

Assuming you have added the reference to the `Kendo.Mvc` and `Kendo.Mvc.Export` dll's into the project.

Failing this working have you tried to use the Telerik Kendo UI for MVC plugin for Visual Studio to upgrade the project as this may also help resolve this issue for you. If you don't have this option this try downloading it either package updater or via the progress updater software for Telerik.

As a side note I noticed in your image that you have a file `System.Web.Http.Cors.xml` which is in errored state. This may be preventing your project from building correctly which could be impacting the dll for kendo from being loaded correctly.

Personally when adding/referencing dll's in a project I prefer to add the files into a lib folder that sits alongside the project rather than adding the files into a bin folder as the bin folder is usually excluded from source control check-ins.